renderPlot: select input from multiple columns in a dataframe
I am creating a shiny app that will display a histogram of all the projects that have been conducted in a particular place across a range of years. However, the data I am using has multiple columns for location (location_1, location_2, ... etc.) and for other categories like author_1, author_2 etc. (that is to say, I cannot recreate the dataframe to have one single column for location without creating an exponentially larger df). My actual data is a few hundred rows, this is just a simplified version.  At the moment my code looks like this:
Data:
df  <- data.frame(
  title = c("Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3"),
  year = c(2021, 2020, 2023),
  author_1 = c("Bob", "Jane", "Taylor"),
  author_2 = c("Alex", "Ann", NA),
  author_3 = c("Charlie", NA, NA),
  location_1 = c("London", "Berlin", "Paris"),
  location_2 = c("Beijing", "Delhi", NA),
  location_3 = c("New York City", NA, NA)
)

ui
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(sliderInput(inputId = "year", 
                            label = "Project Funding Year:",
                            min = min(df$year),
                            max = max(df$year),
                            value = c(min(df$year), max(df$year)),
                            sep = "",
                            step = 1),
                selectInput(inputId = "location",
                            label = "Location",
                            choices = list("London", "Berlin", "Paris", "Beijing", "Delhi", "New York City")),
                plotOutput(outputId = "histogram")
                
)

server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$histogram <- renderPlot(
    df %>% filter(year == input$year,
                  location_1 == input$location) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = location_1))+
      geom_histogram(stat = "count")
    
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Is it possible, for example, in the inputs in renderPlot to select input from across multiple columns (e.g. location_1, location_2,...etc.) in my data frame? Thanks for any advice!

Welcome to SO. You write “ I cannot recreate the dataframe to have one single column for location without creating an exponentially larger df”. I believe this is not true. You simply pivot your data into long format. ggplot2, as part of the tidyverse, works best with tidy data. Your data frame is not tidy at the present time. If you don’t make it tidy, you will always be fighting against the tidyverse’s expectation and your life will be unnecessarily more difficult than it needs to be.

Hi Limey, thanks for your feedback! What I meant by that is that there are many more variables (not included in the example data) with multiple columns. For this example, one row of the data frame would go from one row including Project 1, Location 1, Location 2, Author 1, Author 2 to multiple rows (Project 1, Location 1, Author 1; Project 1, Location 1, Author 2; Project 1, Location 2, Author 1 etc.). I realize the data is not tidy, however that is what I was given to work with, unfortunately.

I was aware that the data you provide is only a sample of your real dataset.  My comment still stands.  You may have been given a dataset in an untidy format, but that is no reason to force yourself into using it in an untidy format.  (Primary evidence for that is the very fact that you have posted your question: it prevents you from doing something you want to do.) A small effort invested at the start of your workflow will save considerably more effort later in your workflow.

Ok thank you! I'll work on finding a way to tidy it without losing information

Putting my advice into action...
First, a utility function to tidy a group of columns (such as location_1, location_2 and location_3)...
pivot_column_set <- function(colName, d) {
  d %>% 
    pivot_longer(
      starts_with(colName),
      names_to = "index",
      values_to = "value",
      names_prefix = paste0(colName, "_") 
    ) %>% 
    mutate(source = colName) %>% 
    select(title, year, index, source, value)
}

[Note that this is not the way I would usually write a function like this.  It doesn't fit the tidyverse ethos for several reasons. It's quick and dirty, but it works...]
giving, for example
pivot_column_set("location", df)
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  title      year index source   value        
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>        
1 Project 1  2021 1     location London       
2 Project 1  2021 2     location Beijing      
3 Project 1  2021 3     location New York City
4 Project 2  2020 1     location Berlin       
5 Project 2  2020 2     location Delhi        
6 Project 2  2020 3     location NA           
7 Project 3  2023 1     location Paris        
8 Project 3  2023 2     location NA           
9 Project 3  2023 3     location NA   

This means you can write
tidyData <- lapply(
  c("author", "location"), 
  pivot_column_set, 
  d = df
) %>%
bind_rows() %>% 
pivot_wider(
  names_from = source,
  values_from = value
)
tidyData
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  title      year index author  location     
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>        
1 Project 1  2021 1     Bob     London       
2 Project 1  2021 2     Alex    Beijing      
3 Project 1  2021 3     Charlie New York City
4 Project 2  2020 1     Jane    Berlin       
5 Project 2  2020 2     Ann     Delhi        
6 Project 2  2020 3     NA      NA           
7 Project 3  2023 1     Taylor  Paris        
8 Project 3  2023 2     NA      NA           
9 Project 3  2023 3     NA      NA 

So now it's an easy matter to tidy your input data, regardless of the number of column sets and the number of entries they each contain. [Though I have made a couple of - hopefully reasonable - assumptions here.]
This makes your app very simple.  Note that I've

corrected your use of input$year to correctly handle a sliderInput that returns a range
added multiple = TRUE to input$year to make it easy to see that the data selection is working correctly
separated the filtering of the data from the rendering of the plot, simply because it's good practice

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "year",
    label = "Project Funding Year:",
    min = min(df$year),
    max = max(df$year),
    value = c(min(df$year), max(df$year)),
    sep = "",
    step = 1
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "location",
    label = "Location",
    choices = list("London", "Berlin", "Paris", "Beijing", "Delhi", "New York City"),
    # Allow multiple selections to demonstrate correct function with limited test data
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  plotOutput(outputId = "histogram")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredData <- reactive({
    tidyData %>% filter(
      # Note correct use of a sliderInput with a range
      year >= input$year[1] & year <= input$year[2],
      # To cater for multiple selections
      location %in% input$location
    )
  })

  output$histogram <- renderPlot(
    filteredData() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = location)) +
      geom_histogram(stat="count")

  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

